# BoxLayout artifact at 125% display scaling

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout, hidpi

This simple Java swing `BoxLayout` UI apparently results in certain pixels not being drawn (resulting in artifacts/garbage) when my display scaling is set to 125% (Windows 10):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) panel.add(new JButton("Button " + i));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        container.add(panel);
        frame.add(container);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
  
}
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot]

There is a one pixel gap between Button 2 and Button 3. I'm not greatly concerned with the gap itself, but the pixels in this gap (within the width of the buttons) are filled with garbage. In the screenshot, this appears to be a misaligned piece of a button, but in general this can change whenever this area is repainted (such as after hovering Button 2), often coming from a recently-repainted component (often more obvious in a more complex application). Presumably this is just uninitialized data due to some kind of dimension mismatch triggered by display scaling and particular position values.

Last tested with openjdk-14.0.2. (Presumably this can only happen since [JEP 263](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/263) added "HiDPI Graphics" support in Java 9.)

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to avoid this problem or work around it? Is this a problem in `BoxLayout` or is it a more fundamental problem? Basically, what's going on?

Comment: Java 8 here. There is no gap between buttons. (Just saying)

Comment: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8253530